# MySQL - Updating two tables, infinite query

Tags: mysql

I want to update two mysql tables with one query, but my query loads for infinite time, crashing the whole mysql service.

I have two tables here:

*users_steam*

[image]

*bets*

[image]

Basically, I need to set **bets.won** to 20.000, updating player's balance at the same time.

```
    UPDATE bets, users_steam
SET bets.complete = 1,bets.won=20000,
users_steam.coins = users_steam.coins + 20000 
WHERE bets.steamid=users_steam.steamid
 AND bets.round = 1337 AND bets.complete = 0
```

This does not work, it makes an infinite query.

Comment: SQL looks correct to me. How many entries do you have in each table?

Comment: I have 237k in *bets* and 30k in *users_steam*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats wrong with your current attempt but instead try it in a trasaction with two separate queries.

```
BEGIN

UPDATE bets
JOIN users_steam on bets.steamid = users_steam.steamid
SET bets.complete = 1,bets.won=20000
WHERE bets.round = 1337 AND bets.complete = 0;

UPDATE users_steam
JOIN bets on bets.steamid = users_steam.steamid
SET users_steam.coins = users_steam.coins + 20000 
WHERE bets.round = 1337 AND bets.complete = 0;

END
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. However, *'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE bets
JOIN users_steam on bets.steamid = users_steam.steamid
SET bets.co'*

Comment: @NedasMikoleika Ah looks like begin/end is only supported inside procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
UPDATE bets b INNER JOIN users_steam u ON (b.steamid = u.steamid)
SET b.complete = 1, b.won = 20000, u.coins = u.coins + 20000
WHERE b.round = 1337 AND b.complete = 0
```